# Interpret Naive Bayes output Python

Tags: python, naivebayes

I am running Python code off Kaggle on the adult dataset using Naive Bayes. How do you interpret the results below, I know that it's for each instance the likelihood they make less than 50K or more than 50k.

How do you interpret say the first  row in simple terms? Why are the numbers not like WEKA outputs. simpler?

```
y_pred_prob_df = pd.DataFrame(data=y_pred_prob, columns=['Prob of - <=50K', 'Prob of - >50K'])

y_pred_prob_df
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @FredNina I think that questio would be more apropiate for StatExchange or DataScience Exchange where are the statistic, ML and DS questions

Comment: The first row simply said the probability of belonging to class A or B is `0.999` and `0.000` respectively (it's using `Scientific notation`), what is weird about that?